# reference key case insensitively

Tags: json, key, jq, case-insensitive

How can I express a case insensitive simple key reference in jq?

E.g., I can have:

```
{
  "key" : "value"
}
```

or

```
{
  "kEy" : "value"
}
```

but not

```
{
  "key" : "value",
  "kEy" : "value"
}
```

Is there a way to express the `.key` filter such that it'll catch `"key"` or `"kEy"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to convert all keys to lower-case as a default format and extract the key name of your choice (inspired from this [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43038520/5291015))

```
with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase ).key
```

The `.key` inside `with_entries(..)` is not to be confused with the key name of your choice, because that is the default name for all key-names when using the family of *entries functions in `jq` - `with_entries`, `to_entries` and `from_entries`

If your keys are nested inside other objects, one would would be `walk` through the entire JSON to recursively rename the keys and fetch the field of your choice

```
def recursive_key_rename:
  walk( if type == "object" then with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase ) else . end);

recursive_key_rename | .key.anotherkey
```

See [jq-play demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uGuiLuSDQp)

Comment: Inia, do you know how to make this work if the JSON document has nested keys. e.g instead of simply `.key`, it coul dhave `.key.anotherKey`

Answer (score 4):

Given `i` flag, the `test` builtin matches case-insensitively, you can use it in conjunction with `to_entries`. E.g.:

```
to_entries[] | select(.key | test("key"; "i")) .value
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SWP_h-UzT9)</sup>